# Unable to restart server after it joins the domain

Tags: powershell, server, remote-server, restart

Morning guys,

I'm running into an issue where I have a script that joins a Server to a Domain and restarts, intalls it's roles/features, etc and then restarts it again. I don't have an issue with the first restart:

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $IP -Credential $AdminCred -Wait -For PowerShell
```

but when I try to do the second restart at the end of the script it get the following error

```
Restart-Computer : The computer is skipped. Fail to retrieve its LastBootUpTime via the WMI service with the
following error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

The following is the original code I tried

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $HostName -Wait -For PowerShell
```

Without credentials, as I expect Kerberos to work as the account from the laptop has proper permissions

but I also ran it with `-Credential` and same error. Then I tried changing `$HostName` to `$IP` and still no luck.

I can get around the error, by enclosing the `Restart-Computer` command into an `invoke-command` session but then I can't "wait for powershell" unless I set an arbitrary sleep timer for a couple minutes.

Any Ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to add the `-WsmanAuthentication` param and specify `Kerberos`. Final code

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $HostName -WsmanAuthentication Kerberos -Wait -For PowerShell
```